# Rails 3- Scope access with current_user and decent_exposure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I successfully set-up the decent_exposure gem as this [railscast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure).

I would like to use scope access with current_user for the edit / update / create action in order to avoid checking the permission by comparing the owner of object with current_user.

Controller :

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController  
 expose(:article)  
 expose(:comments) { article.comments }  
 expose(:comment)  

 def index  
 end  

 def new  
 end  

 def create  
  if comment.save  
   redirect_to comment.article, :notice => "Successfully created comment!"  
  else  
   render :new  
  end  
 end  
end
```

How can I have with decent_exposure something like this in my edit action for example :

```
@comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

i think you could do:

expose(:user_comments) { current_user.comments }

expose(:user_comment)

the user_comment should be scoped to current_user.comments and you would use user_comment would be used in your view.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
`expose :comment, scope: ->{ current_user.comments }`

https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure#scope

Please try.

Adam T, if i get right, decent_exposure will seek for UserAnswer model in this case and fall with uninitialized constant UserAnswer since there is no such model:
`expose(:user_comments) { current_user.comments }`